# (discord.py) keyError: 'wallet'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance")
    em.add_field(name="Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name="Bank", value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

@bot.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    users = await get_bank_data()

    earnings = random.randrange(100)
    await ctx.send(f"someone gave you {earnings} coins.")

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
    with open('mainbank.json',"w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

async def open_account(user):
users = await get_bank_data()

if str(user.id) in users:
    return False

users[str(user.id)] = {"Wallet": 0, "Bank": 0}

with open('mainbank.json',"w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open('mainbank.json', "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users
```

It says key
File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/bot/vibebot.py", line 78, in balance
wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
KeyError: 'wallet'

Im no expert in these kinds of codes, so any help would be much appreicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that “wallet” is not a key in your dictionary, so make sure your JSON is structured as so.

```
{“users”: {“wallet”: 9}}
```